# Remove local resource from web role without deleting deployment

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to publish my solution to an existing Azure Cloud Service web role, but I am getting the following error:

> Windows Azure could not find the resource `DataFilesStore` in the
>   service package. To upgrade the deployment, you must add the resource.
>   Otherwise, perform a new deployment.

I removed the `DataFilesStore` local resource because it is not needed anymore.

I cannot perform a new deployment (or delete the current deployment) because then I will lose the assigned IP address of the service.  This is a production environment so this is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh472157.aspx) that you can't remove a local resource when doing an in-place upgrade. However, you can do so using a VIP swap. Upload your new deployment to the staging slot, do whatever smoke testing you need to do - and then initiate a VIP swap. This does not cause downtime for your application and you will not lose your VIP - since it is only the internal load balancer -> VMs link that is swapped.